# Java Credit Account error

Tags: java, jcreator

I'm having an error compiling this piece of short code, it would be very helpful if you help me to solve it.

```
import java.util.*;

class DriverProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {

      //Create objects of the class

    CreditCardAcct fatherCredit = new CreditCardAcct("Father","121215");

    CreditCardAcct SonCredit = new CreditCardAcct("Son","656565");

      //loop to perform 10 purchases

    for(int vi=0; vi<=10; vi++){

        double valueRandom =(Math.random()*1100);

        System.out.println("Father purchase"+valueRandom);

        fatherCredit.purchase(valueRandom);

        valueRandom = (Math.random()*1000);

        System.out.println("Son Purchase: "+valueRandom);

        SonCredit.purchase(valueRandom);

    }

}

}
```

the error is occurring in these two lines

```
             fatherCredit.purchase(valueRandom);
             SonCredit.purchase(valueRandom);
```

both of the errors are cannot find symbol.

I know this error is not very complicated to solve but I don't see the reason I'm having this error.

thank you everyone and have a good day!

here is my CreditCardAcct class code:

```
 import java.util.*;

 //class CreditcardAcct definition

 class CreditCardAcct {

 //instance variables

String cardHolderName;

String cardNumber;

 //arraylist to store the Listpurchase

ArrayList<Double> Listpurchase;

 //static instance variables of the class

static final double overallAccountLimit = 10000;

static double overallAccountBalance = 10000;

 //Class constructor to initialize the variables

public CreditCardAcct(String ParametercardHolderName, String ParametercardNumber) {

    this.cardHolderName = ParametercardHolderName;

    this.cardNumber = ParametercardNumber;

    this.Listpurchase = new ArrayList<Double>();

}

public void Updatecredit(Double Inputamount){

      //if condition to update the account balance

    if(Inputamount <= overallAccountBalance) {

        overallAccountBalance = overallAccountBalance - Inputamount;

        Listpurchase.add(Inputamount);

        System.out.println("Updated the Purchase!");

        System.out.println("Credit balance: "+(overallAccountBalance));

    }else {

        System.out.println("Insufficient Credit amount, Purchase failed");

    }

}

 //Accessors and mutators of the class

 //To get the Name

public String getCardHolderName() {

    return cardHolderName;

}

 //To get the card number

public void setCardNumber(String ParametercardNumber) {

    this.cardNumber = ParametercardNumber;

}



 //To set the name

public void setCardHolderName(String ParametercardHolderName) {

    this.cardHolderName = ParametercardHolderName;

}

 //To get the purchASE LIST

public ArrayList<Double> getPurchase() {

    return Listpurchase;

}



 //to set the purchase

 public void setPurchase(ArrayList<Double> Listpurchase) {

    this.Listpurchase = Listpurchase;

}



 //To get the card number

public String getCardNumber() {

    return cardNumber;

}



}
```

Comment: don't start variable names with an uppercase...

Comment: Where is your **CreditCardAcct.purchase()** method within the CreditCardAcct Class? I do however see a **CreditCardAcct.setPurchase()** method and a **CreditCardAcct.getPurchase()** method.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, it doesnt appear that you initiated the randNum class...

Random randNum = new Random();
num = randNum.nextInt( x );
try it with this style of random...

This is what i always use and i have no problems with it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you